# jquery regular expression not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm getting error when trying this regex expression:  Output should only match numbers and dot. 1, 2, 3, 1.2, 11.11, 1.10, .40, .60, 0.10

`Invalid regular expression: /\d+\.\d?{2}/: Nothing to repeat`

```
var reg = /\d+\.\d?{2}/;

if ($("#g_C").val().match(reg))
{ alert("match"); }
else
{ alert("no match"); }
```

**updated final answer:** 
 var reg = /^(.\d{1,2})$|^\d+(?:.\d{1,2})?$/;

Comment: *"jquery regular expression not working"* jQuery doesn't have regular expressions. JavaScript does, though.

Comment: What is the value of `$("#g_C").val()`? And what is the expected outcome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using multiple quantifiers

```
var reg = /\d+\.\d?{2}/;
// here ----------^^^^
```

The `?` there means "zero or one of the previous thing" but then you follow it with `{2}` which means "exactly two of the previous thing". At that point, there *is* no previous thing (because the `?` has already been applied).

You either want to remove the `?`, remove the `{2}`, or (if you want a literal `?` there), put a `\` in front of the `?`.

You haven't said what you want, but I'll take a guess that you want either whole numbers (no decimal point), or a number with a decimal point and exactly two places of precision. If so:

```
var reg = /\d+(?:\.\d{2})?/;
```

That means "a series of one or more digits, *optionally* followed by a decimal point and exactly two digits." The `(?:...)` defines a non-capturing group for `\.\d{2}`, and the `?` following it says the entire group is optional.

Comment: Your works, but it also matches 12,00 and 12/00.   How to only allow dot?

Comment: @user1929393: *"it also matches 12,00 and 12/00"* No, it matches *parts* of them. To not match *parts* of the string, you put an anchor at either end: `^` means "start of string" and `$` means "end of string," so: `/^\d+(?:\.\d{2})?$/`

Comment: I tried your new code.  It took care of the comma and slash, but it will not match 1.1, or .10, .2

Comment: You want to match those formats?   I read the question the same way T.J. did: if there's a decimal point. it must be followed by exactly two more digits.  But now it appears your requirements are much looser.  Y'know, if you had included sample inputs and desired outputs in your question, we could have been spared a lot of hassle.

Comment: @user1929393: Please **read** the answer, in particular the bit saying what `{2}` does. If that's not what you want, well, you'll want to change that then.